# Shortcode button dosent work for all posts. Work for first post only

Tags: plugins, php, functions, ajax, javascript

I am creating a custom wordpress theme and i am little stuck in one situation, Actually i added a download link button and add some Java Script on it. The button on all posts showing and downloading fine, but according to the Java Script,the (shortcode button/download link button)  is only clicked 2 times, after 2 times it automatically disappears.

The Java Script code is working fine only for very first post. for other posts it does not work.

here below is my code:-

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                  var i = 0
                     $(".gotocls").click(function(){
                         i++
                            if(i == 2)
                             document.getElementsByClassName('gotocls')[0].style.display = 'none';
                    
                    });
            ``  });
     
         </script>  

          <a class="dkpdf-button gotocls" href="www.downloadlink.com"  target="_blank"><span class="dkpdf-button-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></span> <?php echo $pdfbutton_text;?></a>`
```

Here's a screenshot for the HTML code:

[image]

Comment: why added '[0]' to ur JS, arent u intentionally limiting it to 0, which is the first post... try removing the [0] from the code

Comment: if i remove [0] or if i remove 0 from []  , then code dosent work for 1st post also

Comment: Could u please provide me with the link of the page, as u havent included HTML for the post content, To be honest i didnt really understand your question, the JS u showed is repsonsible for hiding the PDF BUTTON, and not showing the actual posts, and ur question is about why only 1 post is shown...so kinda confused, though it seems to be simple, once I understand the issue

Comment: Well basically i am working on the localserver before making changes to the final live site....however,  from starting point:-

Comment: Well basically i am working on the localserver before making changes to the final live site....however,  starting from starting point:- (1) i have a resume page which show resume posts from wp_usermata table, (2) The client wants a download button on each post so that  he can download  those posts in pdf (download working fine) .(3) Now the client wants that he only wants to download each resume post only 5 times, after 5 time downlaods the download link button should must be disapper. (4) I used the above js so that the download link buttons disapper after 5 clicks.

Comment: (6) Now , for example i have 10 posts :- and on each posts i have download link buttons,,,, The very first resume post downlaod link button is working for 5 clicks,,, the other 9 posts doesent work for 5 clicks,,,the rest 9 posts continue to downlaod post for unlimited times.... Hope you understand

Comment: could you please share the HTML for the posts. or may be screenshot of the inspect element portion, because I suspect there's some issue with your classes rather than actual JS. I am sure that you do not need "[0]"  and I am also thinking that you would need to use each function to bind it with every link on the page, my main concern is that is JS able to detect all 10 download Links or not. Also, why are u using $i == 2 if you want to allow 5 downloads?

Comment: can we share anydesk id?

Comment: check i have attached the ss under the code........(why are u using $i == 2 if you want to allow 5 downloads?) just checkking if downlaod works for 2 time clicks only,,,,,,late i will change to 5,,,, i did 2 to save time and un-necessary downlaods

Comment: I think I get it, could you please change [0] to [1], and then check if the 2nd link is working

Comment: Hey, even I am struggling a little bit, are you capable of editing html at your end, I made my own code, and I am able to count for all 10 posts, but due to some issue, I want to have a parent for it may be a span, in which I can put classes, would it be fine with you to have parent for it?

Comment: ok ,, after  changing  [0] to [1] ,,,,if i click 5 times  on first post download  link button then insted of hiding 1st post download link button,  it hides 2nd post downlaod link button insted......however i havent clicked on 2nd post downlaod link button.........

Comment: My logic was kinda correct, I hope that clicking the 2nd link 5 times also hides the second link right?

Comment: yes ..... it hides

Comment: lets try your code....happy having a helper from same city :)

Comment: check the answer please... I think buggy, but give it a shot and report to me observations of this code

Comment: well i have tried your code but now none of the download link button is working....just downlaoding the pdfs unlimited times

Comment: fine, I think the issue was with data, plus I had a syntax error too, updated answer check now, this time working on my Fiddle so, high hopes

Comment: https://codepen.io/aditya-milyin/pen/OJNxRNy You can visit this, the js has one extra line which changes the html show the link count too, thats just for my personal debugging, so I hope it works for you too...

Comment: Also, I just forgot to tell, that you need to add the `data-click="0"` attribute to each link for it to work

Comment: As per the question i  have asked... you instructed me with a code that works perfectly for me...moving further is there any way to save the clicks for each user.....for example i have 5 clicks of each post downlaod link button...... i used 2 clicks,,,, after login/logout or might  after some days i still want to have the remaining left 3 clicks not all 5 clicks.... all the 5 clicks reloads if we refresh the page.....i want only the remaining clicks it dosent  matter if we refresh the page or not.

Comment: Well sure there is way, using local storage of browser or cookies, But you can ask it in another question, as most readers of answer other than you would get confused, about why I used Local Storage, but its fairly simple imo, so you can try it yourself too

Comment: Okk thanks i try little myself if got any trouble i will ask

Comment: You just need to add unique data attributes to each link, and then link that to local storage, like if x link is clicked, then its data attribute is taken, and the respective link counter in local storage is updated based on it. You can alternatively use AJAX for logged in users, I built similar functionality for dark mode on my site, where I use local storage for logged out users, but user_meta using ajax on logout users

Comment: could you please share me your site link?

Comment: https://milyin.com/ In the right Menu bar, you can find the button to toggle theme, and it works based on local storage

Comment: Friends, can you continue this using the chat feature? Thanks.

Comment: yes.............

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal can you help me with this ??:--  moving further is there any way to save the clicks for each user.....for example i have 5 clicks of each post downlaod link button...... i used 2 clicks,,,, after login/logout or might after some days i still want to have the remaining left 3 clicks not all 5 clicks.... all the 5 clicks reloads if we refresh the page.....i want only the remaining clicks it dosent matter if we refresh the page or not.

Comment: @AlmightHacker sure, I can help you, not a tough thing it is, just post a seprate question, because answering this in current question, is not good for the Stack Overflow community

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal okk sure i will share you the link of new question

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal  heres the link of my question:- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374226/how-to-save-clicks-of-a-downlaod-link-button-while-it-dosent-matter-if-we-refres

Comment: Sure, amm sorry buddy, I am a bit busy, please don't mind I shall need 2 hrs before I can do it. Meanwhile is it possible for u to have different html ID or data attribute for each link for clear distinction

Comment: all right buddy...i am awaiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

So I had asked you few things in comments for your question, you are yet to answer them, But I shall begin with some things.

So I assume that

1.) for 10 posts, each post has 1 download link unique to it,

2.) each link has the class 'gotocls'

3.) Downloading stuff is working correctly, meaning I just need to get it to hide/show when necessary.
4.) each of the 10 download links have at least 1 class common, from your code it seems that the common class is `'gotocls'`

So I pointed out that it does not make sense to use '`[0]`' in your code for getting the element. You pointed out that it works perfectly for the first download link, that is because you are only targeting the first link with [0], I have not tested, but I think, you can get to the 2nd Link, using '[1]' because that's how it works.

HTML should look like this.

```
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
<a class="gotocls" data-click="0">0</a>
```

**Please not that the data-click="0" attribute is really necessary for code to work, so please add it to your html. **

In case due to some limitations you cannot put the data attribute then please use this JS, but I do not recommend JS for adding data-attributed on page load, as html seems to be much more logical and efficient thing to do

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.gotocls').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('data-click', '0');
});
});
```

And your code doesn't work when trying all the 10 link clicks. So, based on the inputs and based on lack of HTML, below is my approach, please try it and let me know in comments to my answer, I think this one should work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".gotocls").click(function() {
     count= $(this).attr("data-click");
     count ++;
       if(count==5){
                $(this).hide();
       }
       else{
            $(this).attr('data-click', count);
       }
   });
  });
```

Comment: as you have instructed me to add data-click="0" in the each link
the above code finally works for me. Thank you for your great help and quick replies. I appreciate your work.

Comment: Super Happy to help you, may you keep growing, I added JS to automattically add data attribute by default just in case you need it. Please upvote if you liked by answer, and stay blessed, and remember Code Is Poetry